# what is the radius of convergence of $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(−1)^k}{k!(n+k)!}\frac{z^{n+2k}}{2^{n+2k}}$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

let be z a complex number. I wanted to find the radius of convergence of this power serie $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(−1)^k}{k!(n+k)!}\frac{z^{n+2k}}{2^{n+2k}}$

Comment: What have you attempted yourself?

Comment: Ratio test${}$?

Comment: i tried ration test but it gived me a fraction with factorial "weird" and can't conclude with a direct ration test because of the form of exposant depending of n and 2k

Comment: i think i have to do a substitution but i dont know exactly how to proceed

Comment: Are you sure that you wrote the expression correctly and there is nothing like $(n+2k)!$ in the numerator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(−1)^k}{k!(n+k)!}\frac{z^{n+2k}}{2^{n+2k}}
=\frac{z^n}{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(−1)^k}{k!(n+k)!}\frac{z^{2k}}{2^{2k}}.
$$
The radius of convergence is 
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{|a_k|}{|a_{k+1}|}
=\lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{(k+1)!(n+k+1)!4^k}{k!(n+k)!4^{k+1}}
=\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{(k+1)(n+k+1)}4=\infty
$$
This gives you the radius of convergence for the series of the variable $z^2$. But it does not change things because the radius is infinite. If it were finite, we would have to take the square root.

Comment: Probably you had in mind $a_k$, not $a_n$...

Comment: Obviously. Thanks :)